# How do you say a "shot" referring to alcohol?

Tags: traducción

What are some common ways of saying a shot of liquor?  This can be referring to a small, usually 1 to 2 ounce drink taken all at once  or can be a measure of liquor.

For example:
I ordered a round of shots for the table.
We took a shot of whiskey.
There are 2 shots of vodka in the drink.

Also, how would you translate "shot glass"?  Wordreference.com translates this as "copita", but I'd like to get some opinions from the real world.

Comment: Cantinero, un shot de tequila ... (we dont really say cantinero tho) means unsurprisingly barman a shot of tequila.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Mexico, we always said... (drum roll)...

> shot

The same for shots of espresso, or flavor shots in a Starbucks latte.

Comment: This is what I've heard, but I'm always very wary of trusting the English word is actually used when I hear people around here (in Texas) use the English.

Comment: @Rachel: I had the same concern, but was told numerous times the word was 'shot', and I can attest to personal experience that "Quiero una mocha grande con cuatro shots" works at Starbucks, without any funny looks. :)

Comment: @Flimzy: This is what is actually known as an anglicism. It means that we are "borrowing" a word from English but it is actually not correct. That is why nobody looks at you funny. That being said, as far as I can tell, there is no word in Spanish that would be an exact translation of "Shot" in this context, at least in Mexico.

Comment: @SergioRomero: Just because a word is borrowed doesn't make it incorrect.  If there was some native English word for "tortilla" or "taco" I don't think anyone would say it was incorrect to use the Spanish loan words.

Comment: **False!** (-1). This question has +14 kviews. The disinformation your answer is generating is terribly high. (Which is your source? Are you a native speaker?...) I do agree some people say *shot*, but lot of people are eager to show off some "English" by using anglicisms. And this people might be less than 10% of the rich, brainless, young people. Kindly consider to amend this answer.

Comment: @SergioRomero That's right. Altough it exists "caballito", and in cases is the best option for translating *shot*.

Comment: @c.p. I'm from Mexico City, and every time I go to parties, people always ask for “shots de tequila”. “Caballito” does exist, but it's more the glass itself than the amount of drink.

Answer (score 48):

In Spain, or at least in parts of it, those small doses of liquor are called *chupito*.
And the glass, either *chupito* too, or *vaso de chupito*.

Comment: For the sentence "There are 2 shots of vodka in the drink." I suggest 'trago' as a translation of 'shot'.

Comment: It can also be referred (and usually is) as "golpes", "There are 2 shots of vodka on the table" could be translated as "Hay dos golpes de vodka sobre la mesa"

Comment: @Bardo No, it can't. Nobody says that.

Comment: @david I live on the north of Spain and I've been using it for years, also every single barman we ever asked for "golpes" understood us perfectly, so it's not something that just we use.

Comment: @Bardo Well, perhaps the barmen are just guessing at what you mean. I doubt you heard that expression from a native speaker, although it might conceivably be a regional difference. I'm Spanish and never heard it used in Madrid or Barcelona (or from anyone else I know for that matter).

Comment: @david I'm also Spanish, and used this expression in all the north of Spain and in Madrid, always with success.

Comment: @david http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=golpe 7th meaning. It's accepted by RAE

Comment: OK, I see. So it's one of those words accepted by RAE but never actually used with that meaning. (At least certainly not in Madrid, regardless of whether you managed to get it understood there.)

Comment: I've often seen "golpe" used in recipes for cocktails. [See some examples here](http://thecocktaildrink.com/?s=golpe)

Answer (score 10):

In Chile it's said *Corto* or *Cortito*, when talking about tequila:

> *Un corto de tequila*

But if you say "shot" it is also understood (more used when talking about vodka):

> *Nos tomamos unos shots de vodka*

A "shot glass" is also called *corto*, or more verbosely: *vaso de cortos*.

Answer (score 9):

***Shot glass***

In Mexico, at least the tall narrow kind of shot glasses we use for drinking tequila are called ***[caballitos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tequila#Tequila_glasses)*** ("little horses", "horsies", or "ponies").

Answer (score 6):

I've always heard of it being referred to as `un trago`

Additionally, the verb `tragar` means `to swallow` so it makes the most sense anyway.
Where I'm from, in the Appalachian Mountains, I constantly hear my elders refer to `a shot` as   `a swallow`... or rather, `a swall'r` if you want to get dialectical about it.

Comment: At least in certain parts of Mexico this seems pretty common

Answer (score 5):

I am adding this summary following what was discussed in [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

---

**Argentina**

- shot

**Chile**

- corto

**Costa Rica**

- un trago de guaro

**Cuba**

- trago

**España**

- chupito (both the shot and the glass)

**México**

- Caballito (*únicamente cuando es tequila*) / shot

**Panamá**

- un trago de guaro

**Perú (Lima)**

- trago corto

Comment: In Lima, Perú it is common to hear *trago corto*.

Comment: In Costa Rica shot of liquor = un trago de guaro. I think other countries also use this phrase.

Comment: Añado esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674).

Comment: En el caso de México, se dice *Caballito* cuando es simplemente tequila, si llegara a ser otra bebida no se le llama *Caballito*, de igual forma, se le dice *shot*

Comment: @Flxtr anímate a darle a [edit] para incluir esta valiosa información, que por eso es community wiki, para que la mejoremos entre todos :)

Answer (score 4):

Chupito in Spain and in Mexico are two VERY different meanings. I learned that word living in Spain and when I said it in Mexico on a resort they all started laughing. Turns out it's a sexual act there. In Cancun, Mexico they use the word "caballito" for a shot of alcohol. That was what I was told, but I'm sure the word shot would work just fine too.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Mexico, and we always say *caballito* to refer both to the glass itself and the amount of drink. I've never heard *shot* used in Spanish, but then I'd only know about Mexico...

Answer (score 1):

There are too many different regional words for that. Not any answer about a signle word will be correct.

Spain: Chupito (for the shot itself), Vaso de chupito (for the shot glass), Trago (for a measure of liquour in another beverage)
Mexico: Caballito/Shot
Peru: Trago corto
Chile: Corto/Shot

Answer (score 0):

## Relevant to México:

I'm surprised no one has considered:
***Un tequila derecho.***
<sup>(Which is served in a "caballito")</sup>

Additionally, as others pointed out caballito is the name of the glass but is casually used to refer to a shot(trago):

**Use cases:**
"Vamos por unos tragos"("Let's go for some drinks".)
"Traigame una ronda de shots"("Bring me a round of shots".)
Al cantinero: "Sirvame un trago"(To the barman: "Hit me".)

[image: a mexican order of caballito shots, called bandera for the colors]
<sub>Image source: wikipedia / GDFL license</sub>

Answer (score 0):

En Cuba se dice dice normalmente "trago".

> "Vamos a tomarnos un trago"

Si estas ya en el bar puedes decir:

> Sirveme un sencillo o un doble.